# How to generate comma separated string in to unbound xml structure

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, transformation, bpel

My Input like below

```
<ns0:input>AZX1,P81,IKJU,RED</ns0:input>
```

I have created target xsd with the unbound element to store the values

```
    <element name="Response">
    <complexType>
   <sequence>
    <element name="parameter" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
     <complexType>
      <sequence>
       <element name="value" type="string"/>
      </sequence>
     </complexType>
    </element>
   </sequence>
  </complexType>
 </element>
```

SO I want the output in the below format.

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:Response  xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/CDM/Append/AppendBPELProcess">
   <ns0:parameter>
      <ns0:value>AZX1</ns0:value>
   </ns0:parameter>
   <ns0:parameter>
      <ns0:value>P81</ns0:value>
   </ns0:parameter>
   <ns0:parameter>
      <ns0:value>IKJU</ns0:value>
   </ns0:parameter>
   <ns0:parameter>
      <ns0:value>RED</ns0:value>
   </ns0:parameter>
</ns0:Response>
```

I tried with oraext:create-nodeset-from-delimited-string function in XSLT but it's giving me an error. Is there any way to populate this output in XSLT or using any template?

Comment: Which XSLT engine are you using? Post the code you have written so far.

Comment: I am using this XSLT on my Jdevloper tool. this is waht I build in xslt `<xsl:template match="/">
      <ns0:Response>
         <ns0:parameter>
            <ns0:value>
               <xsl:value-of select="oraext:create-nodeset-from-delimited-string ('{http://xmlns.oracle.com/CDM/Append/AppendBPELProcess}', /ns0:process/ns0:input, ',' )"/>
            </ns0:value>
         </ns0:parameter>
      </ns0:Response>
   </xsl:template>`

Comment: @Sebastien If it will resolve by template then could you provide me that code

Comment: Does your XSLT engine support XSLT 2.0? It would be much simpler if the tokenize function can be used.

Comment: No. It's supports only xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"

Comment: Then why is this tagged as `xslt-2.0`? Also, if you're getting an error then post the exact code you are using and the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you could do it using a recursive template in XSLT 1.0.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/CDM/Append/AppendBPELProcess"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Response>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns0:input"/>
    </ns0:Response>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ns0:input">
    <xsl:call-template name="inputs">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Recursive template will call itself for all comma separated elements -->
  <xsl:template name="inputs">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($input,',')">
        <ns0:parameter>
          <ns0:value><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input,',')"/></ns0:value>
        </ns0:parameter>
        <xsl:call-template name="inputs">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input,',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <ns0:parameter>
          <ns0:value><xsl:value-of select="$input"/></ns0:value>
        </ns0:parameter>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZW/1

Update : Exclude first element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/CDM/Append/AppendBPELProcess"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:Response>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//ns0:input"/>
    </ns0:Response>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="ns0:input">
    <xsl:call-template name="inputs">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <!-- Recursive template will call itself for all comma separated elements -->
  <xsl:template name="inputs">
    <xsl:param name="input"/>
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($input,',')">
        <xsl:if test="$pos>1">
            <ns0:parameter>
              <ns0:value><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input,',')"/></ns0:value>
            </ns0:parameter>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:call-template name="inputs">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input,',')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos+1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if test="$pos>1">
            <ns0:parameter>
              <ns0:value><xsl:value-of select="$input"/></ns0:value>
            </ns0:parameter>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/a9HjZW/3

Comment: The last value not coming and the output showing as null. '<ns0:parameter>
      <ns0:value/></ns0:parameter>'

Comment: @Harish I fixed it.

Comment: My final query on this, if I want to exclude the first position value (AZX1) always and need the remaining values. How this could be done in the same XSLT. ' Can you help me on this.

Comment: @Harish I updated my solution to exclude the first element.

Comment: comma-separated values it's working as excepted. But when tested giving a single string  `<ns0:input>AZX1</ns0:input>`then the output should be empty as I stated the first position not needed. But the outcome has the value.

Comment: @Harish Updated the answer. You should try to understand the code, having someone write the code for you does not really help you learn the language.